# Got fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer while getting data from .csv file

Tags: ios, arrays, csv, swift, xcode6

I am trying to use [This](https://github.com/naoty/swiftcsv) third party library for get data from `users.csv` file so I add `CSV.swift` file from that library and also add `users.csv` which have data like:

```
id,name,age
1,Alice,18
2,Bob,19
3,Charlie,20
```

and I try to get the data from this `.csv` file this way as mentions in that library description :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let csvURL = NSURL(string: "users.csv")
    var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
    let csv = CSV(contentsOfURL: csvURL!, error: error)!

    // Rows
    let rows = csv.rows
    let headers = csv.headers  //=> ["id", "name", "age"]
    let alice = csv.rows[0]    //=> ["id": "1", "name": "Alice", "age": "18"]
    let bob = csv.rows[1]      //=> ["id": "2", "name": "Bob", "age": "19"]

    // Columns
    let columns = csv.columns
    let names = csv.columns["name"]  //=> ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"]
    let ages = csv.columns["age"]    //=> ["18", "19", "20"]
}
```

but I am getting error at line : `let alice = csv.rows[0]` and the error in console is : `fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer` I don't understand what is wrong here.
This is the screenShot of my project : https://i.stack.imgur.com/32xG9.jpg

Please help me for this.

Comment: You can see that there is no element in your rows array. So it'll definitely crash

Comment: so what is the solution for this? bcz i did same what mention in library description.

Comment: i need values in my arrays

Comment: Print the error object, and it'll tell you the reason why it failed. Are you sure that you have data in that CSV file ?

Comment: yes i am sure and error prints this : `0x0000000000000000`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69646/discussion-between-dharmesh-kheni-and-midhun-mp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the following code is failing to find the file you are referring:

```
let csvURL = NSURL(string: "users.csv")
```

Change that to:

```
let csvURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("users", ofType: "csv")!)
```